# Convolve returns false result

Tags: functions, bugs, symbolic, convolution

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.0**

---

I tried to convolve sin with sin and got this unexpected result:

```
Convolve[Sin[x], Sin[x], x, y]
(* 0 *)
```

Now I know convolution of infinite functions is not well defined, but normalized for the length of the interval, the solution should look like $-\frac{\cos(y)}{2}$. Ignoring that, the answer should at least be $\infty$, or undefined, but definitely not zero.

Any comments, solutions, or condemnations?

(It may be worth mentioning that I am using Mathematica 9.0.1.0.
Also, WolframAlpha gives the same result.)

Comment: This doesn't return anything for me.

Comment: Please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag to your own questions.  This is a special tag that is meant to be added by someone else than the original asker after the community verified that there is indeed a bug.  When you suspect a bug, do add version information, especially if you are not using the latest version.

Comment: 10.0 and later return this unevaluated.

Comment: That is at least more sensible.  Thanks for the info.